# Qlikview filtering specific value in column

Tags: qlikview

I have column which has two values `Import` and `Export`

In a bar chart I want to include only `Import`, How can I filter it in expression?
Is it like

```
<type = {'Import'}>
```

How can I do it in Qlik?

Comment: you need to have some aggregation function but this is a valid set analysis. For example `sum( {< type = {'Import'} >} MyValue)`

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of "Imports" just use:

```
count({<type={'Import'}>} Import)
```

OR

```
count(if(type='Import', Import))
```

The later is slower on BIG data sets, but has its advantages by *NOT* ignoring selections in the "type" field.

use the one that uits your usecase